# Remove php/html extention and trailing slash from url using nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need to remove the *.php* and *.html* extension and the trailing slash from the url without impairing access to existing directories.

I am currently using the following nginx configuration:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

index index.php index.html;
location ~ / {
    rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ /event.php?id=$1&title=$2 last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

It works but I can't access existing folders (expected behavior since ending with a slash produces an infinite redirection). I have tried to fix it with a `try_files` but it has not worked:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @notexists;
}
location @notexists {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ /event.php?id=$1&title=$2 last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string;
}
```

And by the way, I would like to know how to optimize the code for greater efficiency. I'm new with Nginx...

Comment: What is the exact request and response with your second alternative that does not give the result you are looking for?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen When I enter the url `domain.com/about/` it should redirect me to `domain.com/about` which should point to the `about.php` file, but instead it returns 404 error...